# Invoking activity from a service

Tags: java, android

I have a situation with the intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

**The Scenario**

I have a service which launches an activity. This service is used by my android wear application. When I launch the activity I specify the FLAG ACTIVITY NEW TASK flag as mandated by android OS (When you call an activity from a service , it is necessary to apply the NEW TASK flag).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GoodOlActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Supposedly My application is already running and I access my service and get  GoodOlActivity to launch , it would be launched on the top of the task stack (NO NEW TASK WILL BE CREATED , BECAUSE OF AFFINITIES). If i keep on launching this activity , it will keep on having its copies made on the task stack .

### The Problem

Supposedly my application is not in the history stack and I have pressed home and removed it. In such a situation a user uses the android wear application and invokes the service. The service in turn invokes GoodOlActivity. Okay Good . However subsequently GoodOlActivity is never launched and remains the only activity in the task stack .

### Presumption

---

I believe that in the first case , the multiple activites were launched on top of another because the new task was not actually created. The reason being that a task for the target activity existed.

However in the second case a new task was created , hence the constraints of that come into play . The constraints being that if an activity is already in the task stack, just that activity would be brought to the foreground.

### Target

Well both the scenarios (one with the application running , and the other with it being swiped out) should be the same . I should be able to run GoodOl multiple times.  Helppp ?

Comment: Which Android Version are you running this on? Beginning with Android 10 starting activities from services is problematic: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts